# Redirect to page admin if chatbot turned off

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks

I have created chatbot for messenger and now i want to add function when user unsubscribes chatbot then it must send all messages to page with notification. I thought to create table where i will save users who unsubscribed and everytime check if user unsubscribed or not. When unsubscribed then just return 200. But it doesn't send notification to facebook page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the handover protocol to pass control of the chat to the page inbox for unsubscribed users.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol